# parsing string value from file into float where string contains comma

Tags: java, string, parsing, floating-point, double

I have a input file coming into my application with some product prices values in each rows.

However, when the price is higher then 999.99, the values contain , at appropriate place.

```
1,000.00
5,432.89
```

etc.

1) Is there a set rule about placing comma in currency values ? On what basis the place of comma is decided ?

2) Is there a library method to parse such string values to float/double ?

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: what about this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Comment: Any reason for using float/double instead of BigDecimal, which is much more appropriate for prices?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes.. Using big decimal in the app!! but following KISS for stack overflow!!

Comment: @nidhin: How does that help ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to parse and format decimal numbers.

The commas are there for thousands separators. Here's a simple example which deliberately parses to `BigDecimal` rather than to `float` or `double` - binary floating point is inappropriate for currency values.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
        format.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) format.parse("1,234.56");
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Now that just uses the default locale for things like the thousands separator and the decimal separator - you may well want to specify a particular locale, if you know what will be used for the file you need to parse.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on locale ?? How does it affect the formatting ?

Comment: @NikunjChauhan: Different cultures use different ways of displaying numbers. For example, the number "one and a half" may be written as 1.5 in English but 1,5 in French.